# Disabling the Button for only a specific instance of ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have `ng-repeat` on a `div` that contains a button. Say the div repeats 5 times with 5 buttons. I want to disable the 2nd button when it is clicked. How can I disable the button at that index?

`<div ng-repeat='thing in things'>
  <button ng-click='clickToDisable($index)'>button</button>
</div>`

Something like this. I tried `ng-disabled= 'disableButton == $index` but that just disables all of the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the `$event` into the click function and set the disabled attribute to true, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='thing in things'>
  <button ng-click='clickToDisable($event)'>button</button>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.clickToDisable = function(evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybx98tk2/) of it working.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to AngularJS. Like the `$event` and `$index` do you know if there are more I should read and learn about ?

Comment: @AndyNguyen I think you should look into creating directives. You really shouldn't be making DOM manipulations from a controller, that's what directives are for. If you wanted to add this disable functionality to multiple places around your application, you'd have to rewrite the `clickToDisable` for each controller utilizing it. With a directive, you could throw on a custom attribute on the element you'd like to disabled and it would just work on its own.